# Are netcoreapp3.1 packages compatible with net5.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I have a set of C# projects that currently have `netcoreapp3.1` as TargetFramework. They get published to nuget.org as multiple libraries and one executable .NET Core Global Tool.

Some clients of my library want to switch to `net5.0`, but then it seems that they need both runtimes (`net5.0` and `netcoreapp3.1`) installed. Is there no backwards compatibility for `net5.0` projects to use `netcoreapp3.1` libraries?

If I would switch my libraries to `net5.0`, I suppose that this would break clients that still use `netcoreapp3.1`, right?

I found out that I could set `<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>`, but it would be nice to avoid always having to compile and publish separate binaries for multiple framework versions. Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? You'll find out that yes, .NET 5 can reference any .NET Standard/.NET Core version just fine.

Comment: @camilo-terevinto: I actually experimented on a machine with only .NET 5 installed. I found that I can compile my tool, but then running it gives the following error:

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.2 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

However, you are right that referencing the library in a .NET 5 client actually worked. Why is there a difference in compatibility between library and executable binary?

Comment: Because one (standalone 3.1) is an application that needs the framework to be able to run while the other (packaged as reference from 5.0) is just a library that does not need the full runtime installed because the application will take care of that original loading. This also explains why 3.1 -> 5.0 is valid but 5.0 -> 3.1 is not

Comment: Thanks! I would really like to understand this better. Suppose I have library code L and compiled it to package LB using 3.1. Then I have client code A that references LB, which I compile once to AB3.1 using 3.1 and once to AB5.0 using 5.0. Why can the 5.0 runtime execute AB5.0, but no AB3.1? If you can point me to a good reference that explains this compatibility issues, that would be great.

Comment: I don't have any reference at hand and this comes mostly from experience working with the different .NET Core versions. Basically, the 5.0 runtime can run 5.0 apps, the 3.1 runtime can run 3.1 apps, and so on. However, running an app needs *far* more dependencies than what a library needs, as that part is backwards compatible (but understand that making backwards compatible perhaps 5% of the CLR is obviously different to making 100% compatible). That's why you can install both 5.0 and 3.1 at the same time